# IDISPATCH::Invoke to call a method fails with error 0x80020005 type mismatch

Tags: c++, com

I am trying to call a mthod that takes 2 strings here you are the code

```
VARIANT vArgs[2];
                                            VariantInit(&vArgs[0]);
                                            VariantInit(&vArgs[1]);
                                            //VariantInit(&vArgs[2]);

                                    //vArgs[2].pdispVal = pDisptEntries;
                                    vArgs[1].bstrVal = bstrSrc;
                                    vArgs[0].bstrVal = bstrtrgt;

                                    vArgs[0].vt = VT_BSTR;
                                    vArgs[1].vt = VT_BSTR;
                                    //vArgs[2].vt = VT_DISPATCH;

                                    dpEntry.rgvarg = vArgs;
                                    dpEntry.cArgs = 2;
                                    dpEntry.cNamedArgs = 0;
                                    //dpEntry.rgdispidNamedArgs = new DISPID[2];
                                    //dpEntry.rgdispidNamedArgs[0] = 0;
                                    //dpEntry.rgdispidNamedArgs[1] = 1;

                                    UINT index = -1;
                                    EXCEPINFO   ex;

                                    hr = pDisptEntries->Invoke(dispid_Add, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, 
                                        &dpEntry, NULL, &ex, &index);
```

Comment: That specific error message is usually due to one (or more) of the method arguments being of the wrong type - for example, it expects an int and you gave it a string. It's hard to say exactly what's wrong without knowing the details of the object you are invoking against, but I will say that 'Add' type methods don't usually have a source and destination string as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The error code unequivocally tells you that the function does not in fact take two arguments of type string.  Getting the dispid wrong is possible too, it will call the wrong function.  Watch out for the return value, not sure what happens when you pass NULL but the function returns a value.

Comment: Passing NULL when the function returns a value SHOULD just return an error HRESULT, but it depends on the object implementing the IDispatch interface.